# Which Application Programming Interface function does Windows use to translate DNS using nslookup.exe?

Tags: windows, api, dns, nslookup

Does anyone know which Windows API function does nslookup.exe use for DNS translations?
I tried to search for it on the internet, but I didn't find anything.
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: The title is about how to start nslookup.exe, but the question is about how nslookup.exe looks up names after it has started. Please clarify.

Comment: I don't know about Windows specifically, but [the source code for another version of nslookup.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/busybox/latest/source/networking/nslookup.c) uses `getaddrinfo`.